# Encryption over TLS

Tags: ssl, networking, encryption, openssl, tls1.2

I need to implement end-to-end encryption. To do this, I'm thinking of exchanging public keys between two users, then encrypt messages with the public key, and send the message back to the user via the server. Does it make sense to do this messaging over TLS, or would it be redundant? Since the data will be encrypted, I think TLS will be superfluous here, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not only about encryption. You also need a trustful third party to authenticate the website in order to avoid DNS poisoning. That's the job of an SSL/TLS certificate.

Comment: And that`s all what i need for secure messaging?

Comment: Well, that's what HTTPS provides. Until now, it's considered secure. Let's see what quantum computers can do in the near future :)

Comment: But i am not using HTTP/HTTPS, my server is raw TCP server and DNS requests does not exists. What about that case?

Comment: I see, so it's not browsable but still accessible through the internet. In this case, just an encryption mechanism might be enough. Just be aware of DDoS kind of attacks. Maybe you can use a VPN. Also, try to implement some monitor mechanism for the requests and block the server if some upperbound of traffic is ultrapassed. Some authentication mechanism like OAuth2 might also help.

Comment: But if you can, just host your server in a cloud that already implement all these features

Comment: Are you sure? What about ARP poisoning?

Comment: With encryption, the attacker will get encrypted messages if he tries a man in the middle. But it's true that it can compromise the traffic . You can try an ethernet switch that provides dynamic ARP inspection to help mitigating these issues.